# Convert list to a data.frame

Tags: r

I have a column that was made up of links in which I have files in html format. I get that code with this command.

```
tablas <- list()
for(i in 1:length(consumos$Especificaciones)){
  url <- consumos$Especificaciones[i]
  tablas[[i]] = read_html(url) %>% html_nodes("table") %>% html_table()
}

tablas[[1]]
```

Then I have a list of 9, and I want to put this list information in an excel cel.

How can I do it?

Thanks!

Comment: did you try `bind_rows(tablas)` ?

Comment: Okay. So, I don't get your question. Sorry. Please show us your data (at least an example) and what you expect to get. I simply don't understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: I have a link like this http://multimedia.globomatik.net/productsSheet/A0023294.txt
. I took the code with this code:ander <- list()
for(i in 1:length(consumos$Especificaciones)){
  url <- consumos$Especificaciones[i]
  ander[[i]] = read_html(url)
 
  
}        And then, I need to do this with all the columms. If I put this ander[1] R give me only the value 1, but I want to take all the values.

Comment: So the elements of `consumos$Especificaciones` are links like "http://multimedia.globomatik.net/productsSheet/A0023294.txt"?

Comment: Yes Martin, there are links like that.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing I have understood your question properly, here is the slightly modified code I would suggest you to try:

```
n <- length(consumos$Especificaciones) #to simplify the following lines

ander <- vector("list", n) #creates an empty list of length n

for(i in 1:n){
  url <- consumos$Especificaciones[i]
  ander[[i]] <- get_txt(url)
}

#Some different ways to structure the output:
codesDFh <- as.data.frame(ander) #returns a data.frame of 1 row * n columns
codesDFv <- as.data.frame(t(t(ander))) #returns a data.frame of n rows (1 column)
codesV <- unlist(ander) #returns a vector of 9 items (html codes I guess)
```

Or, you may, more simply, create a vector 'ander' to store the results, so that you do not have to 'unlist' it after the loop:

```
codes <- character(n) #supposing your html codes are basic text (of class character)
```

Finally, a general advice in R programming: Try to avoid using names that are already used by the basic functions/variables of the R language, e.g. in your code, you used 'c' yet a base function named 'c' exists (for data concatenation). This will prevent some issues sooner or later.

Comment: Hello MarQ, thanks for your answer. But my problem is , when I only obtained the last html text. I think that I need to do another for-loop outside this  for-loop to obtain the 9 different html text.

Answer (score 0):

One last try:

```r
library(tidyverse)

urls <- c("http://multimedia.globomatik.net/productsSheet/A0023294.txt",
          "http://multimedia.globomatik.net/productsSheet/A0023293.txt")

consumos <- data.frame(Especificaciones = urls,
                       stringsAsFactors= FALSE)

ander <- list()
for(i in 1:length(consumos$Especificaciones)){
  ander[i] <- consumos$Especificaciones[i] %>% gettxt
  Sys.sleep(5)
}

c <- ander %>% as.data.frame
```

Do you want this?